# Measure for network spatialisation

Tags: co.combinatorics

---

Here is a question that Tommaso Venturini, from the Media Lab of Sciences-Po in Paris, asked me on a topics which is out of my field. Could you give me some hints or/and some references I will forward him?
Thank you very much.

---

The visual analysis of networks is becoming more and more popular among social scientists, who appreciate the possibility it offers to analyze social graphs without having to deal with complex mathematics.

Based on tools that allows the graphical manipulation of networks (e.g., gephi.org), this type of analysis has its pillar in the techniques of spatialisation, which aim at making graphs 'readable' by arranging nodes meaningfully. The most common spatialisation techniques is based on the so-called 'force-vector' algorithms. These algorithms work by simulating a physical system where nodes repulse each other and arcs work as springs keeping nodes together. By reaching a stable equilibrium, force-vector algorithms draw closer nodes that are directly or indirectly connected, and draw apart nodes that are not connected. What is crucial in force-vector spatialisation is that it makes the relative position of nodes significant: two nodes are close in space if they are close in connectivity (they are connected to the same nodes). Thanks to spatialisation, networks become maps where the basic notions of graph mathematics (seeing clusters, structural holes, bridges, centrality and marginality...) are expressed in a visual form. No wonder, social scientists like spatialisation.

To our knowledge, there is not yet any convincing measure of the quality of a network spatialisation. Intuitively, we know  that there is a connection between the quality of the spatialisation and the presence of structural holes or, to be more precise, the uneven density of arcs distribution (generally speaking, networks that clusterize better also spatialise better). Intuitively, we also know that there are force-vector algorithms that are more efficient than others (the resulting networks are more readable). Yet, we are still looking for a measure that would allow us to asses, or at least compare, the quality of the spatialisations produced by different networks or different algorithms. Do you know any?

---